# How can I create a new url in a Django app?

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have implemented a model in a Django app and I would like add an url to handle the view for this model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     text = models.TextField()
     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I would recommend that at a minimum you go through this tutorial before you do anything else: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/. Showing you how to write a url pattern won't do you any good at this point.

Comment: @Fabi G Your question is vague. Please update it to ask a more specific question than just "can you help me?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the Django tutorial as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

However, to answer your question, you could do a setup like this:

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

def my_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.my_view, name='my_view')
]
```